# Transpiler in IBM Quantum devices

Tags: quantum-gate, programming, qiskit, quantum-algorithms

I am having trouble understanding how the transpiler works in IBM quantum computers. I am studying the spatial noise correlation between two qubits in an IBM Q device. For that, I don't want the transpiler to change my input circuit. **Is it possible to overwrite the transpiler?** Can someone explain how the transpiler works?

Comment: I have asked a question before(https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/15045/qubit-connectivity-of-ibm-quantum-computer) and it is alike your problem, maybe the answers are helpful.

Answer (score 3):

When transpiling you can set the optimization level to 0, to prevent the transpiler from doing anything but unrolling to the natural basis gates of the device, eg., `circuit = transpile(circuit, backend, optimization_level=0)`.

Comment: In addition to unrolling to the device's basis gates, it may also change the circuit in order to fit the device's connectivity

Comment: Information about the transpiler: https://qiskit.org/documentation/apidoc/transpiler.html and https://qiskit.org/documentation/tutorials/circuits_advanced/04_transpiler_passes_and_passmanager.html